# Interpolating FRA curves for MPC dates

Tags: interest-rates, forward-rate, interpolation, forward-start

I have data for all the "white" FRAs with 3m fixings in a given market, i.e., 1x4 up to 9x12 and all the central back MPC meeting dates over the next twelve months.

What is the recommended method for interpolating "what is priced in" for the 3m fixing in the future for those MPC dates. Cubic interpolation is a bit a "blunt tool" as the 3m fixing will likely "jump" the day after the MPC decision (if there is a cut or hike expected).

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it!